# Reading bytes out of a character array using a character pointer in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am using a code on an Arduino Uno. What I have been trying to get this code to do, is to go through my array of bytes, called "sample" and calculate a CRC-32 value in hexadecimal. I have confirmed that this code calculates CRC_32 successfully, but only when treating "sample" as an ASCII string. To understand more clearly what I mean, have a look at:
[enter link description here](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html)

On that web page if you put "sample" as a continuous string (i.e. 82818030.....), while the ASCII dialog box is selected, you will get a particular answer which is different with when the HEX dialog box is selected. I have been trying to achieve that result (which is 0x430F8AB5).
I would appreciate any help.

Here's the code:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
//#include "lib_crc.h"



unsigned char sample[90] = {
  0x82,0x81, 0x80, 0x30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x21, 0x46, 0x01, 0x1D, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x3F, 0x01, 0x22, 0x22, 0, 0x06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x80, 0x0E, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xFA, 0, 0, 0x27, 0x85, 0x07, 0x0F, 0x4C, 0x82, 0x80, 0, 0, 0, 0x05, 0x01, 0xC1, 0x13, 0x1D, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x3F,0x01, 0x22, 0, 0x06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xFA, 0, 0, 0x27};
//unsigned char sample[] = "828180300000214611D00003F1222206000000000000080E0000FA0027857F4C828000051C1131D00003F122060000000000000800000FA0027";



static PROGMEM prog_uint32_t crc_table[16] = {
  0x00000000, 0x1db71064, 0x3b6e20c8, 0x26d930ac,
  0x76dc4190, 0x6b6b51f4, 0x4db26158, 0x5005713c,
  0xedb88320, 0xf00f9344, 0xd6d6a3e8, 0xcb61b38c,
  0x9b64c2b0, 0x86d3d2d4, 0xa00ae278, 0xbdbdf21c
};

unsigned long crc_update(unsigned long crc, byte data)
{
  byte tbl_idx;
  tbl_idx = crc ^ (data >> (0 * 4));
  crc = pgm_read_dword_near(crc_table + (tbl_idx & 0x0f)) ^ (crc >> 4);
  tbl_idx = crc ^ (data >> (1 * 4));
  crc = pgm_read_dword_near(crc_table + (tbl_idx & 0x0f)) ^ (crc >> 4);
  return crc;
}

unsigned long crc_string( unsigned char*s)
{
  unsigned long crc = ~0L;
  while (*s)
    crc = crc_update(crc, *s++);

  crc = ~crc;
  return crc;
}

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print(crc_string(sample),HEX);

}

void loop() // run over and over
{ 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your crc_string() function is doing:

```
while (*s)
  crc = crc_update(crc, *s++);
```

which will stop at the first null byte - I think you want to loop for the whole length of the byte array (which is not a zero-terminated string) which I guess is 90 bytes.
i.e.

```
unsigned long crc_string( unsigned char*s, unsigned int length)
{
  unsigned long crc = ~0L;
  unsigned int i;
  for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    crc = crc_update(crc, *s++);

  crc = ~crc;
  return crc;
}
```

and call `crc_string(sample,90)`

Note that your commented string `828180300000214611D0...` is junk because a zero byte is represented by a single '0' not '00'.

Comment: +1 That commented string is junk in more ways than just that. The entire string is asci chars and not raw hex-bytes. Thus the reason the uncommented string (with your code in use) will work and that sample string will not.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I now get:

Comment: Disregards my previous comment.
Thanks for your suggestion. I applied your changes. However, I now get BA63CB8E as my CRC which is still not correct. I was wondering, could it be something to do with the way the pointer is pointing to the elements of "sample"? Also I found this on the Arduino forum:

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=222414.0

Down the bottom there seems to be some relevant stuff. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Why do you think is it not correct? That forum link shows the same incorrect code. Using the CRC convertor link you gave in the question, copy and paste this string (fixed with '00' for zero) and select HEX: `82818030000000002146011D000000003F012222000600000000000000000000000000800E00000000FA00002785070F4C82800000000501C1131D000000003F01220006000000000000000000000000008000000000FA000027` also try running your fixed function: `crc_string("123456789", 9)` and compare that with the CRC site's ASCII example

Comment: You guys are absolutely correct. I sincerely apologize for my carelessness and thanks a lot for following up the matter.